# Run make to build the shared object file win64

Tags: c++, makefile

I want to use [some lib for python, that is written in c++](https://github.com/hjweide/a-star). In the desc author say I should `run make to build the shared object file`. (I am into necessary folder) When I run `make Makefile` it returns me `make: Nothing to be done for 'Makefile'`. What should I do to create required file?

Comment: Run `make`.  Don't run `make Makefile`.  By running `make Makefile` you're asking make to build the target `Makefile`, which already exists, so there's nothing to do.

Comment: @MadScientist add it as an answer if you want me to accept it. Thank you c: